# Apache Beam Python on FlinkRunner Failing with java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I am new to Apache Beam and I have created a simple [python pipeline](https://github.com/Spazzy757/data-services-comparison/blob/master/scripts/main.py) that I run with the following command:

```sh
python scripts/main.py \
       --runner FlinkRunner \
       --flink_master localhost:8081 \
       --setup_file scripts/setup.py \
       --environment_type EXTERNAL \
       --environment_config localhost:50000 \
       --database postgres \
       --input /dataset/league_of_legends.csv \
       --database_host db \
       --table_name league_game_board \
       --database_user postgres \
       --database_password postgres
```

Technical Details:

- Apache Flink Version: 1.10.1
- Kubernetes Version: 1.18
- Python: 3.8.5
- Minikube: 1.12.3
- Apache Beam: v1.23
- Apache beam python SDK: 3.7

I have set up an apache Flink cluster on minikube which I then port-forward the Jobmanager so that when I run the above script it will submit the job. I copy the datasets into the containers using `kubectl cp` and exec into them to make sure the data is found in the correct location. All seems to go well until the Job reaches the Taskmanager. The Task manager Submits the job to the Apache Beam Server but then fails with the following output in the logs:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/qv/ztv4pp7n4r1gv38m2pj94l_00000gn/T/beam-tempabvjrxov/artifactsal8uquz5/9a7e79a7285955a56f5ab55fa5eb522eeb5a7bfcbbfe616a6b0bef5314a21ee8/1-ref_Environment_default_e-workflow.tar.gz (No such file or directory)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystem.open(LocalFileSystem.java:118)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystem.open(LocalFileSystem.java:82)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.open(FileSystems.java:252)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.artifact.ArtifactRetrievalService.getArtifact(ArtifactRetrievalService.java:121)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.artifact.ArtifactRetrievalService.getArtifact(ArtifactRetrievalService.java:96)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.model.jobmanagement.v1.ArtifactRetrievalServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ArtifactRetrievalServiceGrpc.java:327)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:172)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onHalfClose(Contexts.java:86)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:331)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:817)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 taskmanager  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The Beam Job Server Then Fails with a similar error:

```
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 beamserver 2020/08/20 06:19:56 Failed to retrieve staged files: failed to retrieve /tmp/staged in 3 attempts: failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/workflow.tar.gz
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 beamserver   caused by:
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 beamserver rpc error: code = Unknown desc = ; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/workflow.tar.gz
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 beamserver   caused by:
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 beamserver rpc error: code = Unknown desc = ; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/workflow.tar.gz
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 beamserver   caused by:
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 beamserver rpc error: code = Unknown desc = ; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/workflow.tar.gz
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 beamserver   caused by:
flink-taskmanager-585fc984d8-hhzg2 beamserver rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
```

The Setup for my minikube Flink Cluster can be found [here](https://github.com/Spazzy757/data-services-comparison/tree/master/environments/local_flink/manifests).

I have searched for any reference to this `/tmp/staged/workflow.tar.gz` and to the `1-ref_Environment_default_e-workflow.tar.gz` but can't seem to find any reference on how to supply this to my setup.

Question here is what is this tarball and how do I give it to my Flink Cluster

Comment: Can you try removing the flags --environment_type EXTERNAL --environment_config localhost:50000?

Comment: So this was my original setup which then the --environment_type defaults to DOCKER, and as I am running in Kubernetes this requires docker in docker setup and I run into this problem https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6020 which is currently unsolved

Answer (score 0):

workflow tarball is file created by setup.py

```
 import setuptools
 setuptools.setup(
    name='PACKAGE-NAME',
    version='PACKAGE-VERSION',
    install_requires=[],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
 )
```

Without it your code will work only if its self contained in one file without any other folders with code.
You provide --setup_file parameter with path to setup.py.
WARNING: setup.py must be named setup.py. Cannot provide your own name.